# Upper bound for size of topology needed to falsify a non-tautology in IPC

Tags: general-topology, logic, intuitionistic-logic

I was attempting to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350678/can-we-make-intuitionistic-logic-intuitive) with an algorithm based on [an answer I gave](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219159/exercise-verification-no-topology-over-a-finite-set-generates-as-a-set-of-theor?noredirect=1&lq=1) as an exercise posed by Z.A.K [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4218858).

I think it is easy to show the decidability of IPC by converting to S4 and then appealing to the decidability of some tableau calculus for modal logic.

However, I feel like it should be possible to prove this by computing a conservative upper bound on the size of topology that one needs to check for a well-formed formula of a given size.

I am completely stuck on the inductive step when attempting to prove a bound on the size of finite topologies that I have to check.

My strategy was going to be, for an arbitrary formula $\varphi$, to pick a *really dumb* upper bound on the size of topologies I am going to look at, and then look at all the finite topologies over sets of that size or smaller.

Let $|\varphi|$ be the number of variables + the number of connectives in $\varphi$.

For safety, I will pick $2^{|\varphi|}$ as the size of the largest set to look at.

Consider all possible topologies on $[1..2^{|\varphi|}]$, with the whole space as the sole designated truth value in each topology $\tau$.

It's easy enough to prove that this bound works for well-formed formulas of the form $A$ and $\lnot A$ (as well as trivially $\top$ and $\bot$).

However, I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to induct on the structure of $\varphi$.

It isn't clear to me how much I have to grow the maximum size of my allowed topology to refute $\lnot \varphi$, given that $n$ refutes a formula of length $|\varphi|$.

Is there an easy bound and a straightfoward way to prove it?

Is the bound perhaps different for each connective? (On a rough impressionistic level, $\land$ seems to suggest maybe looking at a box topology or something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the punchline:

> If $\varphi$ is an S4 formula that isn't provable, then there must be a (topological) model $X$ so that $X \not \models \varphi$ and $|X| \leq 2^n$, where $n$ is the number of subformulas of $\varphi$.

Imo, the "standard, straightforward" way to prove this actually goes through the [kripke semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_semantics) for S4. We know that if an S4 formula isn't provable, then it's refutable in *some* world of *some* kripke model, say with worlds $W$ and relation $R$. We can then run a "[filtration argument](https://builds.openlogicproject.org/content/normal-modal-logic/filtrations/filtrations.pdf)" to ensure the refuting model is finite:

Define an equivalence relation on $W$ so that $w_1 \sim w_2$ if and only if they agree on all subformulas of $\varphi$. That is, $w_1 \models \psi$ if and only if $w_2 \models \psi$. Call the set of equivalence classes $W^*$, and notice there are at most $2^n$ of them, where $n$ is the number of subformulas of $\varphi$ (since any world thinks that a given subformula is either true or false).

Next we put a relation on $W^*$, which isn't complicated, but is too long for me to want to write down here. This relation is chosen so that, for any subformula $\psi$ of $\varphi$,

$$(W, u) \models \psi \implies (W^*, [u]_\sim) \models \psi.$$

You can find a description of this relation in section fil.8 [here](https://builds.openlogicproject.org/content/normal-modal-logic/filtrations/filtrations.pdf).

So now what do we know? If $\varphi$ is refutable, then it's refutable in a kripke model of size at most $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of subformulas of $\varphi$ (since we can apply the above machinery to get the satisfiability of $\lnot \varphi$).

We then translate this result to the topological setting by using the topology of [upper sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set). In particular, if $(W,R)$ is some kripke model, then we define a topological model $(W,\tau)$ on the same underlying set. The open sets of this space are exactly the upwards-closed subsets of $W$, and it turns out that (under the usual topological semantics) $(W,\tau), u \models \varphi$ if and only if $(W,R), u \models \varphi$.

So then, viewing the refuting kripke model $W^*$ as a topological model in this way, if $\varphi$ is refutable, it must be refutable in a topological model of size at most $2^n$ -- as promised.

As a quick aside, notice this is actually *doubly* exponential to compute with. There are on the order of $2^{2^n}$ possible kripke relations on a model with $2^n$ worlds.

---

I hope this helps ^_^